# Wait after showing MDI child form - alternative to DoEvents

Tags: vb.net, showdialog, mdichild, doevents

A co-worker made some improvements to my app, but at the same time, he changed the whole app to use MDI child forms. So where I used to be able to use ShowDialog() to make the subroutine wait until the new form closed to continue, now I can't. I adapted some old VB6 code to try and replicate the same functionality, but it uses DoEvents() and I've been told to avoid that at all costs.

At this point I can't help but feel like there's just a fundamental flaw in my methodology here, and that there is probably a far simpler way to accomplish the same task.

```
    Private Sub Label_EditNode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label_EditNode.Click
        Dim Frm As New frmVariableEditor With {
            .Tag = "FrmVariableEditor",
            .MdiParent = FrmMDIMain,
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            .Location = Me.Location,
            .Size = Me.Size,
            .myFieldName = "NodeClick",
            .myResultText = txbNodeClick.Text
        }

        Frm.Show()
        Call WaitOnFormUnload()

        txbNodeClick.Text = Frm.myResultText
    End Sub

    Public Sub WaitOnFormUnload()
        Dim bIsLoaded As Boolean = True
        Dim FormName As String = Me.MdiParent.ActiveMdiChild.Name ' Form.ActiveForm.Name
        Do While bIsLoaded
            bIsLoaded = False

            For Each f As Form In Application.OpenForms
                If f.Name = FormName Then
                    bIsLoaded = True
                    Application.DoEvents()
                    Exit For ' breaks the for loop
                End If
            Next f
        Loop
    End Sub
```

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from using `ShowDialog(Me)` (`Dim Frm As New frmVariableEditor Frm.ShowDialog(Me)`). Or use DataBindings, so you won't need a Dialog and whatever changes you make in `frmVariableEditor` will be reflected immediately in the calling Form (or whatever else shares the same BindingSource(s)).

Comment: Btw, if you use `ShowDialog()`, don't forget to set `Frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent` (or CenterScreen, or otherwise specify the location of the Dialog, otherwise it will be shown in a semi-random location). Also, you, of course, don't set `.MdiParent = FrmMDIMain`

Comment: Perhaps you need to adjust your thinking from "I need to wait for the form to close then do something" to "i need to attach an event handler that does something when the form closes" - i mean, after all, you don't jam your app up waiting for your button to be clicked, you attach an event handler that does something when the button is clicked.

Comment: @CaiusJard That's exactly what my coworker suggested, when I brought up the problem with him (after posting my question here). However, personally I'm just not aware of a good way to accomplish it. I need several things to happen on the original form after the secondary form closes, which utilize the data created and/or modified by the second form.

Comment: @CaiusJard My coworker's suggestion required saving the data to be transferred (the contents of the Frm.myResultText variable) into a public variable somewhere, to be collected later on in the original form's .activated event. IMO, all of that seems at least as convoluted as what I'm already doing. That's not to say that it might not be better, I'm just not at all certain about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goes a something like this:

```
Private Sub Label_EditNode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label_EditNode.Click
    Dim Frm As New frmVariableEditor With {
        .Tag = "FrmVariableEditor",
        .MdiParent = FrmMDIMain,
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        .Location = Me.Location,
        .Size = Me.Size,
        .myFieldName = "NodeClick",
        .myResultText = txbNodeClick.Text
    }

    AddHandler Frm.FormClosing, AddressOf RetrieveBlahData

    Frm.Show()

End Sub

Private Sub RetrieveBlahData(sender as Object, e as FormClosingEventArgs)
   txbNodeClick.Text = DirectCast(sender, frmVariableEditor).myResultText
End Sub
```

Probably doesn't get more minimal than that, except for maybe sharing a single data object:

```
    Dim Frm As New frmVariableEditor With {
        .Tag = "FrmVariableEditor",
        .MdiParent = FrmMDIMain,
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        .Location = Me.Location,
        .Size = Me.Size,
        .myFieldName = "NodeClick",
        .DataSetToBindTo = Me.DataSetWhatever
    }
```

You'll have to re-code your form so that it takes this passed in dataset (or other data container) and gets its data from it (databinding) .. then as the editor form is changing the data, it's actually changing the original dataset in the main form too, because they're the same thing